# The page isn't redirecting properly , server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete

Tags: php, .htaccess

WHEN I TRY TO OPEN MY WEBSITE LOGIN PAGE IT IS SHOWING THE ERROR LIKE '" the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete" ...I THINK THE PROBLEM MIGHT BE WITH THE .HTACCESS!.. PLEASE HELP ME WITH IT?

HERE IS THE .HTACCESS:

Turn on URL rewriting

```
RewriteEngine On
Installation directory <BR>
RewriteBase /<BR><BR>
Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly<BR>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f <BR>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL <BR>
RewriteRule .*/ index.php/$0 [PT,L] "
```

am not that sound in coding stuffs..could you pleas help me with it..btw i have successfully test this project on my system using wamp server...its an open source project for blood donor database please help me with it?.. am giving a link for all the related files for downloading...please download and check whats wrong with it..thanks in advance ....link:   http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1351767344

Comment: All this htaccess file does is take any requests and move them to index.php. if index.php doesn't contain logic to handle the form submission then there will probably be an issue..

Comment: thanks..am not that sound in coding stuffs..could you pleas help me with it..btw i have successfully test this project on my system using wamp server...its an open source project for blood donor database please help me with it?.. am giving a link for all the related files for downloading...please download and check whats wrong with it..thanks in advance ....link:   http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1351767344

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your page is redirecting back you to the same page i.e, login page, that's why you got this error. Try to check your coding once again where the page is redirecting you???

Comment: thanks..am not that sound in coding stuffs..could you pleas help me with it..btw i have successfully test this project on my system using wamp server...its an open source project for blood donor database please help me with it?.. am giving a link for all the related files for downloading...please download and check whats wrong with it..thanks in advance ....link:   http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1351767344

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the response header to be sure of the problem. A few ways you can do this, [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) a GUI application or you can run

```
curl http://www.yourhost.com -I
```